# spring batch read write execution time

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm looking best way to measure execution time of Spring Batch read, procced and write action.
In [Meta-data](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/2.0.x/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) there are information about whole step but not about each action.

I'm thinking about [listeners](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/2.0.x/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution) but is it proper solution ?

Thank you for all of Yours answers!

Answer (score 2):

The beforeXXX and afterXXX methods of [ItemReadListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemReadListener.html), [ItemProcessListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemProcessListener.html) and [ItemWriteListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html) interfaces are the correct way to measure in-step performance.

Just initialize your timer at beforeXXX() and output the result at afterXXX() method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Serkan Arıkuşu, i did like this and works fine.

Comment: This approach is good, when we have single batch job. Do we have any other approach to apply as a common pattern to all batch jobs, instead of injecting the code for every step.