# Measuring performance of individual items ( reader, processor and writer ) - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

My Question is very similar to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446366/spring-batch-read-write-execution-time) i.e. I wish to measure performance of individual items - reader , processor and writer.

As suggested in answer to linked question, I added an `ItemReadListener<T>` but that is giving me time for each read item while I am using `JdbcPagingItemReader` and want time taken to read each page and not individual item.

Similar would be the case for processor too ( that is , it will give me time for each item ) while I want time spent by processor in preparing a whole chunk.

A `ChunkListener` doesn't look suitable either since that would again measure combined time of reader, processor and writer.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: You can use VisualMV to profile your application

Comment: I want to log these times in application logs for future use and analysis. I can effectively log only writer times since that takes a `List` of items and I measure time taken to finish `write` method but for reader and processor, all I can do is measure time for single item and that is very much useless.

Comment: You could write an aspect that would record the times involved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a not thread safe simple example of a possible solution to counting execution time of the processor when processing one individual item and also logging the total execution time.

```
public class PersonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonItemProcessor.class);
    private static int count;
    private long processTime;

    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {
        count++;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        final String firstName = person.getFirstName().toUpperCase();
        final String lastName = person.getLastName().toUpperCase();

        final Person transformedPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName);

        // bear in mind that this will pollute the logging when processing millions of records
        log.info("Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");
        log.info("Processing 1 item took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1e3 + " sec");

        processTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;    

        // use some interval value, here I used 5.
        // last few items won't be counted e.g. 18 items you will see this message 3 times.
        if (count == 5) {
            log.info(String.format("Processed %d items in %s sec", count, processTime / 1e3));
            count = 0;
        }
        return transformedPerson;       
    }

    public long getProcessTime(){
        return processTime;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code you can find [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/). Just adjust the processor to above to see the effect.

Same logic can be applied to reader/writer.

Comment: I guess, you need to also  reset `processTime` inside `if (count == 5)`. I have added my chunk size as an instance field to processor and am comparing `count` with that, leaving edge cases i.e. for a chunk size of 1000 and total items being 5423 , log will be printed five times only.

Comment: If you are only interested in the processTime of a certain amount of items (here the 5), then yes. 
And as indicated in the comment of my example, residue items will not be counted.